# Can I read a txt file every few seconds and display its contents through html?

Tags: php, html, ajax, txt

I have a txt file that updates with new data every few seconds. It is stored and generated locally on a raspberry pi, which will also act as the server.

I want its contents to be added to and html code for displaying.

It should update without manual reloading of the page.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe with AJAX, PHP, or something along those lines?

Don't have to find/write any code for me, as I understand that it would be rather time consuming. just point me in the right direction so I can learn how to do it.

Comment: Typically AJAX requests are used for this: you create a static html page that is loaded once. Inside that page you have a client side logic (javascript) which periodically performs a AJAX request (use a framework like `jquery` for that) and uses the response to update the data shown on that stage. So you have a live updating visualization. The request needs to be responded to by a small server side logic (php) which indeed reads the file for each polling AJAX request. The data is trypically handed over in `JSON` format in such a setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using an API endpoint and an ajax call on the client.
I sketched up some code for you.
I made the endpoint url /url/to/api.php - you would change this to match the server setup on the pi.

You would also need to host a HTML file that has some javascript code that polls your api every few seconds. I set it to do this every 5th second, using setInterval.

```
<script>
// The client code (javascript) - should be placed right before the </body> tag
(async () => {
    setInterval(async () => {
        const data = await fetch("/url/to/api.php").then(response => response.text());
        document.getElementById("#htmlElementWithThisId").innerHTML(data);
    }, 5000);
})()
</script>

// In the html you have to have an element with the id: "htmlElementWithThisId" - this is where the content will be displayed

<div id="htmlElementWithThisId"></div>
```

Finally in the api.php file you would read your file and "echo" the contents of your file on every request

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jQuery`,`$.ajax` ,`$.post` or `$.get`

or can also use `XMLHttpRequest` for javascript (old but gold)

and for php use `readFile` (server-side no need for API)

little story may help

once i used arduino with wifi module

i collected the data using the arduino, after that i passed it to esp8266 (the wifi modle) and i posted to my site using `GET` methode
like
http://mySite.lo/?firstVar=myFirstVar&secondVar=mySecondVar
and the server took the `GET` data from the URL

update:
the refresh of page

for php it's  `header("refresh: 3;")`

for js write `setInterval(location.reload(),3000)`